# New Messaging System API for non developer accounts

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

According to [this blog post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/591/) the new messaging system should be accessible via the API (fql/graph) for non developer account as of end of November. It still gives OAuthException with message "You must be a developer of the application".

I was unable to find any updates on this issue from Facebook or other sources. Anyone knows what is going on with this and when will it be accessible?

There was a [bug opened](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/206899726060879) on the subject, anyone who has interest in this might consider promoting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going to answer my own question, according to the [response on the bug](https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/206899726060879) seems like the official answer is:

*"We said it would be published but it wasn't, so just wait until we say it will be published again".*

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to read messages or send them? It's still not possible to send them but reading them should work for any app now

Comment: trying to read messages, using either Graph API /thread or FQL by querying the unified_thread table. Both give me the same error for non developer accounts.

Comment: Is there a migration setting in your app settings for this? it may need to be enabled before you can use the new tables

Comment: I couldn't find anything related to messaging in my application's migration settings. Can you tell me what's the specific setting I need to enable?

Comment: I thought maybe it was the 'New Mailbox back-end' migration mentioned here: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/591 no?